# Migration from WES7 to Windows 10 IoT

Tags: windows, migration, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to port my application written in C and C++ from Windows Embedded System 7 to Windows 10 IoT. I have done preliminary analysis on dll/drivers/third party components which are being used and they are available in Windows 10.

Right now, I am considering there will be errors/warnings to solve. Based on any of your past experience would like to know what kind of errors I might land up with? Also to note, I am changing from VS2012 to VS2015.

Comment: I don't have an answer, and I'm sorry for that.  I am curious to know any problems you encounter.  Please share them, should you come across anything interesting.

Comment: Which edition do you want to migration to: Windows 10 IoT Enterprise, Windows 10 IoT Mobile Enterprise or Windows 10 IoT Core?

Comment: It would be enterprise edition of IoT.